# How to fetch query parameters in a template?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I am using Meteor 1.2.1 + iron-router with autopublish turned on

I would like to construct an anchor href based on collection values returned by a helper *and* query params

Is it possible to do this in the template tag, e.g. `query_param1` should be read from the URL?

```html
<template name="dataEntry">
  {{#each data}}
    <li>
      <a href="/listing?name={{name}}&color=<query_param1>">
       Data name
      </a>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Above, `{{name}}` is returned by the collection and query parameters are appended to that to create a full hyperlink for the `href`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use URL parameters using Meteorjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22120489/how-to-use-url-parameters-using-meteorjs)

Comment: not really - let me rephrase the question

Comment: I think there is no url parser on the client, if that's what you meant. You'll need to parse the url search query yourself, but there are tons of javascript snippets out there for that. Once you have the value, you just return it from a helper and use the helper in your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @Stephen's suggestion like this.

In your template html,

```
     <template name="dataEntry">
        {{#each data}}
            <li>
                <a href="/listing?{{queryParams}}">
                    Data name
                </a>
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </template>
```

In your template JS,

```
Template.dataEntry.helpers({
   "queryParams": function () {
       var name = "";
       //get name from collection here like...
       //name = Meteor.user().profile.firstName;
       var color = Router.current().params.color;
       return "name=" + name + "&color=" + color;
    }
});
```

Or you can use two separate helpers

In your template html,

```
     <template name="dataEntry">
        {{#each data}}
            <li>
                <a href="/listing?name={{name}}&color={{color}}">
                    Data name
                </a>
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </template>
```

In your template JS,

```
Template.dataEntry.helpers({
   "name": function () {
       var name = "";
       //get name from collection here like...
       //name = Meteor.user().profile.firstName;
       return name;
    },
   "color": function () {
       return Router.current().params.color;
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you - that was it - 2 separate helpers, one for the collection, another to return query params - and I can concatenate them in the template

Answer (score 1):

You can access an IronRouter param through a helper, e.g.:

```
Router.current().params.query_param1
```

Comment: yes, I am aware of that - the hyperlink needs to be made up of attribute values from a route and query params in the current URL, both